# X-Forwarded-Host header of OracleCloud LoadBalancer adds port alongwith the host. Is this correct?

Tags: reverse-proxy, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, x-forwarded-for

As per my understanding, whenever there is a forward proxy or loadbalancer in the network, it must keep only the Host part in it. But the LoadBalancer used in OracleCloudInfrastrcture is adding both the Host as well as port separated by a colon(:).

Due to this my application logic, and perhaps Swagger-UI is failing. Is this allowed as per the specs?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-Host

Comment: These headers aren't formalized yet. And Oracle has documented this here: https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Balance/Reference/httpheaders.htm#:~:text=X%2DForwarded%2DHost,original%20server%20handling%20the%20request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These headers aren't formalized yet. And Oracle has documented this here: [https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Balance/Reference/httpheaders.htm#:~:text=X%2DForwarded%2DHost,original%20server%20handling%20the%20request](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Balance/Reference/httpheaders.htm#:%7E:text=X%2DForwarded%2DHost,original%20server%20handling%20the%20request)

One will need to parse the host part through this header accordingly.